# Issue with Custom Select Options [Magento System Configurations]

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, custom-options, module

I am working on an extension. On setting up the configuration options, I am getting error while trying to fetch options for my select variable.

My System.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <checkout  translate="label" module="orderid">            
            <groups>
                <ci_orderid translate="label"> 
                    <label>Custom Order Id</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <ci_orderid_active translate="label">
                            <label>Enable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </ci_orderid_active>

                        <ci_orderid_payment translate="label">
                            <label>Payment Gateway</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>CI_OrderId/Gateway</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </ci_orderid_payment>
                    </fields>
                </ci_orderid>
            </groups>
        </checkout>
    </sections>
</config>
```

On loading the configuration I am getting blank screen and an error is showing on system log file.
Error:

```
2015-03-18T07:15:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/CI/OrderId/Model/Gateway.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/m18/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-03-18T07:15:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/CI/OrderId/Model/Gateway.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/m18/app/code/local:/var/www/html/m18/app/code/community:/var/www/html/m18/app/code/core:/var/www/html/m18/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/m18/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Gateway.php(Model/Gateway.php)

```
class CI_OrderId_Model_Gateway {
    public function getActivePaymentMethods() {
        $methods = array(array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('--Please Select--')));
        return $methods;

    }
}
```

Config.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <CI_OrderId>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </CI_OrderId>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <orderid>
        <class>CI_OrderId_Helper</class>
      </orderid>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <orderid>
        <class>CI_OrderId_Model</class>
      </orderid>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

It is showing like, system cannot locate my class. Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: can you show Gateway.php?

Comment: Post updated with the code. Please check.

Comment: Can you also show the config.XML?

Comment: config.xml added in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<source_model>CI_OrderId/Gateway</source_model>
```

With:

```
<source_model>ci_orderid/gateway</source_model>
```

add this in Config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
                <resources>
                    <all>
                        <title>Allow Everything</title>
                    </all>
                    <admin>
                        <children>
                            <system>
                                <children>
                                    <config>
                                        <children>
                                            <ci_orderid translate="title" module="ci_orderid">
                                                <title>CI OrderId</title>
                                                <sort_order>10000</sort_order>
                                            </ci_orderid>
                                        </children>
                                    </config>
                                </children>
                            </system>
                        </children>
                    </admin>
                </resources>
            </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: It was like that before. I changed it on getting the error.

Comment: See my update answer

Comment: I am still having the error.
I am able to see the configuration settings on commenting out the "ci_orderid_payment" part in system.xml
Thanks.

Comment: I think just adding `orderid/gateway` will do the trick reading the config.